# HTML and CSS href don't work

Tags: html, css

i made this page yesterday and href links doesn't work...

HTML and CSS source here: https://titanpad.com/jmAHmU3GyI

Comment: your link does not lead to the code.

Comment: edited   //casualtext for adding comment

Answer (score 1):

I may not understand exactly what you're asking, but the href attribute belongs inside an anchor tag, like so:

```
<td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
```

**Specification:** http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/0mtto06n/

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `href` attribute on `<li>` elements which is unfortunatelly not going to work. To create links use `<a href="yourUrl">Link text</a>`

Read more here:
[about a tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)